# Removing an array within an array in mongodb

Tags: arrays, mongodb

Within my mongo collection, I have a nested variable of called "institution.type". This is an array with the following elements:

```
db.collection.distinct("institution.type") 
[
null,
[
    "boarding"
],
"virtual"
]
```

I am trying to remove the entries with the "boarding" element, however am getting stuck due to the fact that boarding itself is within an array ( a mistake initially made when using "$push" to an array)

I have tried the following to find the documents:

```
db.collection.find({"institution.type":{ $in: ["boarding"]}}).count()
0
```

and

```
db.collection.update({"institution.id":"somenumber"}, {$pull:   {"institution.type.1":"boarding"}})
"type" : [
        "virtual",
        [ ]
         ]
```

How can I remove the brackets along with the "boarding" tag without getting the error of

JavaScript execution failed: SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier ?

Any advice would be greatly appreciated and welcomed!

Answer (score 1):

To find the item with the boarding subarray you have to use double brackets like so...

```
db.collection.find({"institution.type": {$in: [["boarding"]]}})
```

To pull the item out do the following:

```
db.collection.update({"institution.type": {$in: [["boarding"]]}}, {$pull: {"institution.type": ["boarding"]}})
```